# How to Create database for objects in Android

Tags: android, database

In my app I have 3 edit text and a save button, I want to store these values on a button click using db4o.But it is showing a null pointer exception.

Logcat Details:

```
11-12 14:29:32.566: W/KeyCharacterMap(12122): No keyboard for id 0
11-12 14:29:32.594: W/KeyCharacterMap(12122): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-12 14:29:41.694: D/AndroidRuntime(12122): Shutting down VM
11-12 14:29:41.694: W/dalvikvm(12122): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:205)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at java.io.File.init(File.java:189)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:139)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.io.FileStorage.exists(FileStorage.java:29)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.io.StorageDecorator.exists(StorageDecorator.java:23)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.internal.IoAdaptedObjectContainer.openImpl(IoAdaptedObjectContainer.java:42)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase$1.run(ObjectContainerBase.java:140)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.foundation.DynamicVariable.with(DynamicVariable.java:54)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.foundation.Environments.runWith(Environments.java:28)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.withEnvironment(ObjectContainerBase.java:161)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.open(ObjectContainerBase.java:131)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.internal.IoAdaptedObjectContainer.<init>(IoAdaptedObjectContainer.java:35)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerFactory.openObjectContainer(ObjectContainerFactory.java:18)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.java:65)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.example.db4object.Db4ObjectsHelper.OpenDb(Db4ObjectsHelper.java:23)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.example.db4object.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 14:29:41.963: D/dalvikvm(12122): GC_CONCURRENT freed 310K, 52% free 2733K/5639K, external 410K/517K, paused 13ms+9ms
11-12 14:34:42.160: I/Process(12122): Sending signal. PID: 12122 SIG: 9
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: yes sure...i have edited my question. You can check over there...

Comment: 11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded.java:65)
    11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.example.db4object.Db4ObjectsHelper.OpenDb(Db4ObjectsHelper.java:23)
    11-12 14:29:41.863: E/AndroidRuntime(12122):    at com.example.db4object.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)                   please post the code in above error lines

Comment: private void onClickListener() {
  mbtnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    getEditTextValue();
    dbHelper.OpenDb();
    dbHelper.StoreContact(person);
    dbHelper.getAllContacts();
    dbHelper.CloseDb();
         
   }

Answer (score 1):

Database creation is a pain in Android. Its better to use `ContentProvider` API and it is even harder.

The below library is very simple and you can make use of `ContentProvider` as well. (For inserting and querying the database)

https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/ProviGen

Answer (score 0):

Go through the examples [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-db4o-android-application) and [here](http://wiebe-elsinga.com/blog/android-and-databases/)

This will be helpfull for you in creating db4o databse in android

Comment: How to checkthe output?I mean how to check if the tables have been created or not?My SqlLite Database browser 2.0 is not supporting db4o